# ¿Cómo imprimir en pantalla los elementos de una estructura desde una función en C?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

es mi primer participación en el foro.

Tengo poco que empece a estudiar programación, soy alumno de primer semestre de desarrollo de software.

Ya dicho eso, estoy atorado en este tema.

Estoy trabajando con una arreglo de estructuras, las cuales tiene que registrar los datos de personas tales como nombre, edad etc... Hasta el momento he podido crear el menú y guardar los datos en la memoria, pero no tengo  idea de como podría tener acceso a los datos almacenados al escribir el nombre solamente de alguno de las personas registradas.

Aquí pongo mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Se declara una estructura global con un arreglo de 3*/
struct citas {
char nombre [50];
char hora [6];
int edad;
float peso;
float estatura;
} paciente[3];

/* Prototipo de las funciones*/
void reservar (struct citas paciente[]); //Funcion para reservar cita
void consultar (void); //Función aun en construccion pretende accesara 
los datos e imprimir en pantalla

int main () {
int i = 0, m;

do {
    printf ("ELIGE UNA OPCION\n\n");
    printf ("1. Agregar cita\n\n2. Consultar cita \n\n3. Salir del 
    Sistema\n");
    scanf ("%d", &m);

    switch (m) {
        case 1:
        /* llamada a la función para reservar la cita*/
        reservar(paciente);
        break;
    case 2:
    /* Lamada a la función para concultar datos e imprimir en pantalla 
        */
        consultar();
        break;
    case 3:
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf ("No valido\n\n");
        continue;
    }

} while(i < 3);


}

/* función aun en construcción, registra los datos de la estructura*/
 void reservar (struct citas paciente[]){
  int i;

  for (i=0; i < 0; ++i) {
    printf ("\nNombre: ");
    scanf ("%s", &paciente[i].nombre);
    printf ("\nHora: ");
    scanf("%s", &paciente[i].hora);
}

}

/* En esta función necesito ayuda, es la que va imprimir los datos
de X paciente que se busque por medio del nombre*/
void consultar (void){

}
```

Se que aun no código tiene muchos errores, son partes que puedo resolver, sin embargo la última función es la que no tengo ni idea como atacar ese problema.

Agradezco el tiempo y saludos, espero andar por estos foros bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a tu consulta de como acceder a los elementos de una estructura te dejo unos ejemplos, siguiendo tu ejemplo:

```
struct citas {
char nombre [50];
char hora [6];
int edad;
float peso;
float estatura;
} paciente[3];
```

Por ejemplo, quiero acceder y mostrar por pantalla el nombre

```
printf("nombre: ",paciente[0].nombre)
```

Accedes a las propiedades del struct con el ".", en este caso accedo a la persona guardada en la posicion [0] y luego con el operador "." accedo a la propiedad nombre

Te dejo un link con info de como trabajar con struct en c, por si te es util
https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Estructuras_y_Uniones

Comment: Pues muchas gracias, me esta funcionando, ahora mismo estoy refinando mi código.
Aprovecho para pedir sugerencias al publicar ya que quiero hacer mas preguntas siguiendo esta publicación.

Para publicar el código, es mejor publicar todo o solo el modulo el cual quiero modificar.
Soy novato por este foro y pido las sugerencias de las practicas que tienen.

Saludos!

Comment: Me alegro de que te sea util!. Con respecto a tu consulta, te invito a ingresar al siguiente link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help donde encontraras info sobre normas de como formular preguntas.

Comment: En mi caso, suelo publicar solo el/los modulo/s con el que estoy teniendo inconvenientes. Igual eso depende. Te pido que marques la respuesta como respuesta (clickear el check) para que quede marcada como resuelta la consulta

Comment: Disculpa Cristian, si deseo seguir comentando sobre este código, será mejor abrir una nueva pregunta o solo editar mi pregunta, borrar lo que puse y poner el nuevo código?

Comment: No hay problema! y mucha suerte!